# 'res.location(path)' does not do anything? (Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, httprequest

I have been searching around for answers on *Stack Overflow*; non have worked... Why does `res.location(path)` not work? My Location-header does not change. Normal rendering works fine.

I could add, that in the final code, I want to render the page. So, I want to replace `res.end()` with `res.render('app', {...})` and use *handlebars.js* for rendering.

**Code that does not work as expected**:

```
app.get('/sub-link/:wildcard', (req, res) => {
    res.location('/new-header');
    res.end();
});
```

I have been reading the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.location); could not find the reason. The only thing I found that could be the problem, is the browser:

> *After encoding the URL, if not encoded already, Express passes the*
>   *specified URL to the browser in the Location header, without any*
>   *validation.*
>
> *Browsers take the responsibility of deriving the intended URL from the*
>   *current URL or the referring URL, and the URL specified in the*
>   *Location header; and redirect the user accordingly.*

- I have tried this with the latest Node.js compatible with Firebase SDK 2018 *(server)*
- I have tried this in Google Chrome and IE Edge *(client)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`res.location` doesn't set the response status code to 3xx or 201. It only set the [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) header.

You can use `res.redirect` instead which set the status code to 302 and will make the browser change the URL.

> The Location response header indicates the URL to redirect a page to.
>   **It only provides a meaning when served with a 3xx (redirection) or 201**
>   (created) status response.

This will work:

```
app.get('/sub-link', (req, res) => {
    res.location('/new-header');
    res.send(302);
});
```

or

```
app.get('/sub-link', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/new-header');
});
```

You can check [res.location](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/2f8ac6726fa20ab5b4a05c112c886752868ac8ce/lib/response.js#L826) & [res.redirect](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/2f8ac6726fa20ab5b4a05c112c886752868ac8ce/lib/response.js#L857) code to see the differences between them.

Comment: Ah, I understand. I misunderstood the use of it.