# Node, Express.js. Cannot get POST request to pass tests on Chai

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, chai

I am going over an exercise with Chai testing. I cannot my POST route to pass the tests.

Here are the two errors I am getting:

```
1) Todo API:

   POST /v1/todos

     should create and return a new todo when provided valid data:

 AssertionError: expected header 'location' to have value /v1/todos/5c84450e466b4b769a39cdc1 but got undefined

  at chai.request.post.send.then.res (test/server.test.js:114:27)

  at <anonymous>

  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)

2) Todo API:

   POST /v1/todos

     should respond with 400 status when given bad data:

 Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

I don't know how to set the header in the response. And, I'm not sure why my conditional is not catching the bad data case. I have it on this [glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/boggy-mastodon?path=server.js:1:0)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly because it's an async test, you probably need to call 'done' like this:

```
it('should do something async', function(done) {

    someasyncstuff().then(function(results) {
        done()
    }
}
```

Secondly, you need to specify the actually location header you want to send in server.js:

```
res.location('/mylocationheaderhere');
res.status(201).json(...);
```

for example here: ['res.location(path)' does not do anything? (Express)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50242524/res-locationpath-does-not-do-anything-express)

Lastly, if you want to use the 'id' in server.js - you need to send it in the body in your test code:

```
const newItem = {
        'title': 'Do Dishes',
        id: 12345
      };
```

Comment: For the header problem, I tried to set it like you said. The tests want it to point to the id of the newly created Todo. But I am getting undefined. The glitch should be updated with the change.

Comment: in your server.js glitch you've used 'res.id' - I think you need just 'id'

Comment: I'm still getting undefined with just 'id', can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: yes - you're not adding id to the request body in the test